# Multiple Input Boxes to Create Different Emails

Tags: vba, outlook, inputbox

Here is what I have been given to try and create:

User creates an email a few times per week and has to re-type everything, a request for employee updates, with up to 5 people on it.  Easy enough to create in VBA, except that the employees could change each time.  So there could be just 1 person, or 2, or 3, etc...and each time it could be a different mix of the employees.  They want input boxes that would prompt how many employees for the email, then based on that input, follow-up boxes (if more than 1) that allow the input of the names (1 per box).  It then needs to create the email, placing the input box data into the body text.  Each email text will be based on the input from the 1st input box, so it can adjust for the number of employees (so there could be up to 5 employees on each email).

How do I assign values to my variables (findstrs and foundcells)so that they will adjust to the inputs of the inputboxes without writing all the IF stmts?

```
Dim aOutlook As Object
  Dim aEmail As Object
  Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
  Dim strbox As String
  Dim stritem As String
  Dim X As Long
  Dim r As Long
  Dim LR, lookrng As Range
  Dim findStr As String
  Dim nameCol As Range
  Dim nameCol1 As Range
  Dim nameCol2 As Range
  Dim nameCol3 As Range
  Dim nameCol4 As Range
  Dim foundCell As Variant
  Dim foundCell1 As Variant
  Dim foundcell2 As Variant
  Dim strname  As String
  Dim strBody As String
  Dim sigString As String
  Dim signature As String
  Dim findstr1 As String
  Dim foundrng As Range
  Dim valuefound As Boolean
  Dim strFilename As String

   Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
           Case olInspector
                Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
           Case olExplorer
                Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End Select                        

    If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
        signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
    Else
        signature = ""
    End If

    Set oReply = oMail.ReplyAll

   Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
    Case olInspector
        Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case olExplorer
        Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
   End Select       


Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oReply = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'Input box(es)

    findStr = InputBox("Enter Number of Employees")
    findstr1 = InputBox("Enter Name of First Employee")
    If findStr = "2" Then findstr2 = InputBox("Enter Name of Second Employee")
    If findstr1 = "T1" Then foundCell1 = "<B>Test 1 ID#0000</B>"
    If findstr1 = "T2" Then foundcell2 = "<B>Test 2 IDO#0001</B>"
    If findstr1 = "T3" Then foundcell3 = "<B>Test 3 ID#0002</B>"
    If findstr1 = "T4" Then foundCell4 = "<B>Test 4 ID#0003</B>"
    If findstr1 = "T5" Then foundCell5 = "<B>Test 5 ID#0004</B>"
    If findstr2 = "T1" Then foundCell1 = "<B>Test 1 ID#0000</B>"
    If findstr2 = "T2" Then foundcell2 = "<B>Test 2 IDO#0001</B>"
    If findstr2 = "T3" Then foundcell3 = "<B>Test 3 ID#0002</B>"
    If findstr2 = "T4" Then foundCell4 = "<B>Test 4 ID#0003</B>"
    If findstr2 = "T5" Then foundCell5 = "<B>Test 5 ID#0004</B>"



'Greeting based on time of day

    Select Case Time
           Case 0.25 To 0.5
                GreetTime = "Good morning"
           Case 0.5 To 0.71
                GreetTime = "Good afternoon"
           Case Else
                GreetTime = "Good evening"
    End Select           


sigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Update.htm"

        If Dir(sigString) <> "" Then
         signature = GetBoiler(sigString)
         Else
         signature = ""
        End If


    If findStr = "1" Then
        strBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Can you please update the following:  <br><br>" & _
        "<B>" & foundCell1 & "</B><br><br>" & _
        "Please update this batch.  " & _
        "I Appreciate your help. Let me know if you need anything.<br><br>" & _
        "Thanks <br><br>" & _        
        subject = "Employee Update"

    ElseIf findStr = "2" Then
        strBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Can you please add changes for the following: " & _
              "<ol><li><B>" & foundCell1 & "</B><br><br><br><br>" & _
              "<li><B>" & foundcell2 & "</B><br><br>" & _

        subject = "Multiple Employee Requests"
    End If


'Sets up the email itself and then displays for review before sending

With oReply
.HTMLBody = "<Font Face=calibri>Hi there,<br><br>" & strBody & signature
.To = "superman@krypton.com"
.CC = "trobbins@shawshank.com "
.subject = "Multiple Employee Updates"
.Importance = 2



.Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Any Better Now?

Comment: A little - at least now we know what you're trying to achieve without reading through a wall of text & code. If I understand correctly the relevant part of the code is the `If findstr1 =` and `If findstr2 =` stuff? You need a mapping/lookup between "T{n}" and the values you're assigning to `foundCell`. Can you trim down the code to reduce the problem space to the *specific* issue? A [mcve] usually makes it much easier to work with.

Comment: You're going to need a `For` loop somewhere. Also I'd recommend naming your variables after how they're used and what they mean rather than after their data type, e.g. `nbEmployees` instead of `findStr` and `employeeName` instead of `findstr1` - you'll need that part inside the loop, and the wording will need to be tweaked, lest you need a function to determine whether to write "first", "second", "third", etc., given the current index of that loop. I'd suggest to just use the loop index e.g. `"Enter the name of employee " & i`, where `i` is the `For` loop counter.

Comment: Sure, I can trim it down, but in the past I always get asked to post the WHOLE sub, not just a part.  Yes, the main issue is that section.  I have been trying to do with a loop using 'for' and 'next' but am having trouble doing so using the inputs given that the inputs change based on the number of employees they will need.  So if they say 1, then that is that.  But if they say 2, 3, 4, 5 then I have to account for each combination.

Comment: Ha, typing at the same time!  Yes, that is what I am trying to do but do not know how to make it work with the inputboxes and the i loop counter.  I have done that in other subs but not when it is based on varying possible inputs.  Say, 2 employees, so this name and then this name.  How do I tell it to loop based only on each input and the names added?  Does that make sense?  Also, yes, I am changing the variables naming for sure.  This was just to get me going.  Thank you.

Comment: I've posted an answer, hope it helps. I'm really confused with your "employee names" stuff. Where I come from an *employee name* isn't a string like `T1`, `T2`, etc. - I guess you'll adapt the code as needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this code down into multiple, smaller and parameterized scopes.

Make a `Function` that returns the body of the email given a `Collection` of batch numbers.

```
 Private Function GetEmailBody(ByVal batchNumbers As Collection) As String
```

Now, the calling code needs to know how many employees there are. Make a function for that.

```
Private Function GetNumberOfEmployees() As Long
    Dim rawInput As Variant
    rawInput = InputBox("Number of employees?")
    If StrPtr(rawInput) = 0 Then
        'user cancelled out of the prompt
        GetNumberOfEmployees = -1
        Exit Function
    Else If IsNumeric(rawInput) Then
        GetNumberOfEmployees = CLng(rawInput)
    End If
End Function
```

That'll return `-1` if user cancels the prompt, `0` for an invalid input, and the number of employees otherwise.

```
Dim employeeName As String
Dim nbEmployees As Long
nbEmployees = GetNumberOfEmployees
If nbEmployees = -1 Then
    Exit Sub 'bail out
Else If nbEmployees = 0 Then
    'reprompt?
    Exit Sub 'bail out, cancelled
End If

'fun part here

Dim emailbody As String
emailBody = GetEmailBody(batchNumbers, employeeName)
```

And now the fun part: you need to add as many items to some `batchNumbers` collection, as you have `nbEmployees`. Because you know how many iterations you'll need before you start looping, a `For` loop will do.

```
Dim batchNumbers As Collection
Set batchNumbers = New Collection

Dim batchNumber As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To nbEmployees
    batchNumber = GetBatchNumber(i)
    If batchNumber = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'bail out:cancelled/invalid
    batchNumbers.Add batchNumber
Next

Dim body As String
body = GetEmailBody(batchNumbers)
```

Where `GetBatchNumber(i)` is yet another function call, to a function whose role it is to prompt for an employee number and lookup & return the corresponding batch number, returning an empty string if prompt is cancelled or no match is found.

```
Private Function GetBatchNumber(ByVal index As Long) As String
    Dim rawInput As Variant
    rawInput = InputBox("Name of employe " & index & ":")
    If StrPtr(rawInput) = 0 Then
        'cancelled
        Exit Function
    Else 
        Dim employeeName as String
        employeeName = CStr(rawInput)
        GetBatchNumber = GetBatchForEmployee(employeeName)
    End If
End Function
```

If the mappings really actually look like `T1 -> <B>Test 1 ID#000</B>` then you can probably use this:

```
Private Function GetBatchForEmployee(ByVal employeeName As String)
    Dim digit As Long
    digit = CLng(Right$(employeeName, 1))
    GetBatchForEmployee = "<B>Test " & digit & " ID#" & Format$(digit - 1, "000") & "</B>"
End Function
```

If your mappings are actual mappings then you can have a `Dictionary` lookup in here, or look them up on an Excel worksheet, a CSV or XML data file, a SQL Server database, whatever.

But first, *break things down*. A procedure that starts like this:

> ```
>   Dim aOutlook As Object
>   Dim aEmail As Object
>   Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
>   Dim strbox As String
>   Dim stritem As String
>   Dim X As Long
>   Dim r As Long
>   Dim LR, lookrng As Range
>   Dim findStr As String
>   Dim nameCol As Range
>   Dim nameCol1 As Range
>   Dim nameCol2 As Range
>   Dim nameCol3 As Range
>   Dim nameCol4 As Range
>   Dim foundCell As Variant
>   Dim foundCell1 As Variant
>   Dim foundcell2 As Variant
>   Dim strname  As String
>   Dim strBody As String
>   Dim sigString As String
>   Dim signature As String
>   Dim findstr1 As String
>   Dim foundrng As Range
>   Dim valuefound As Boolean
>   Dim strFilename As String
> ```

...is a procedure that's doing way too many things.

Comment: Yikes wow, thanks Mathieu, I am overwhelmed and trying to go through all this now.  Jeez, you did a lot, thanks!